# Error on Eclipse for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT macro

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-errors, mutex, thread-priority

I am working in Eclipse (Version: Kepler Service Release 1) for a ARM based board. I have setup the Cross compiler configurations. The program is multi threaded. And the program was compiled without any errors. I wanted to set the attribute of a mutex to PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT, so I added the code for that in the program.

```
pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol(&AttributeVariable,PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT);
```

After that I started getting an error for the project telling,"Symbol 'PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT' could not be resolved". I cant figure whats going wrong.!

Comment: And what is the programming language?

Comment: @grer-449 I work in C.